# Flow - Formulas for Conditions - Error in referenced formula because of lookup and ISBLANK

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, lookup

We are migrating workflow rules to flows. *Formulas for Conditions* is used because of cross-object references (not shown in image below).

Now I also need to include in that formula for condition a reference of formula(text) field to check if the result is blank. Now the problem is that if the formula in the formula field contains a reference to a *lookup*, the "error in referenced formula" happens. The interesting thing is that if `ISBLANK` is replaced by `ISNULL`, the formula becomes valid, but of course `ISNULL` is not the correct solution.

The image below is a simplified reproduction of the error: the `Formula_1__c` contains a lookup `Link_1__c`.
[image: Sample "Error in referenced formula"]

Is there a workaround for this, aside from copying the whole formula in `Formula_1__c` inside the Formulas for Conditions (which is what we did for now)? If this is a bug, where can I report this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the error in your workflow rules?  Also, is your flow before-save or after-save?  As for reporting it, you can open it case with Salesforce.

Comment: The workflow rules have no error, as well as the usual "Field-Operator-Value" condition (`Formula_1__c` - Equals - Empty String). As for flow, it is after-save because of email alert, but I don't think it matters here because the problem is in formulas for conditions.

Comment: Was there any update on this, I'm running into a similar issue. It appears that there is something wrong with using a formula field that references a cross object relationship.

Comment: @KB2021 We just settled on "moving the logic of what is in the formula to the condition formula itself." Here is the response I received on the case I submitted last year: *"This is because Formulas in entry criteria that use Formula fields involving traversals are currently not supported by Salesforce. The workaround, for now, is to use the formula instead of the reference to that formula."* If you want to log the case, you may reference mine: #43135224.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that what you're seeing is a bug, so I'd submit a case to follow that lead to validate whether or not what you're trying to do is supported.

I would also consider moving the logic of what is in the formula to the condition formula itself. This may or may not be possible depending on what else the formula field is referencing besides the lookup, but entry condition formulas do support traversing up the lookup chain directly.

I see in the comments that this is after-save, but for the sake of those reading along, I'd also like to point out that if this was a before-save Flow, I'd *really* avoid using a formula field since those won't be calculated yet at the time of entry condition evaluation.