# Mystery Error Message For Flow Entry Criteria Formula

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am attempting to use a formula entry criteria in an after save flow. However, I run into errors when checking the syntax. My starting formula for the flow is exhibit 1) and when I click check syntax I get the error messages in exhibit 2) and exhibit 3). Strangely when I remove {!$Record.Group_Type__c} = "Brand", from the formula I get the error message in exhibit 4). I don't understand why it would say that field doesn't exist when it absolutely does and is available in the FLS (Visible).

I've submitted this case to SF and the person helping me says it is an issue with the flow formula evaluating the formula fields in exhibit 5) and exhibit 6)(both text formulas) at runtime. I suppose that because they are formula fields the flow formula is looking up to a nonexistent value? I don't fully understand how thats possible for an after save flow.

It's possible this has something to do with referencing a formula field that uses a cross-object reference but I haven't seen any SF documentation around a limitation like that. Plus I don't understand how the exhibit 1) formula could work in a formula field but not in a flow formula entry criteria (It also works as a flow variable inside the flow).

Any help or clarification on this would be amazing, I'm fully stuck.

Exhibit 1)
[image: Flow Entry Criteria]

Exhibit 2)
[image]

Exhibit 3)
[image]

Exhibit 4)
[image]

Exhibit 5) - {!$Record.Logo_Name_Text__c}
[image]

Exhibit 6) - {!$Record.Group_Type__c}
[image]

Comment: 1) Is this on a V59 sandbox?  and 2) Does running user have FLS on `Brand__c` and Read on Brand__c Sobject?

Comment: @cropredy it's in V58 and I have admin permissions on the Brand__c. It definitely feels like a bug, but not getting clear answers from the SF case.

Comment: try cloning the flow and simplifying the condition to see if it related to the formula field (you could replicate the formula as an entry condition to the flow

Comment: @cropredy So found a similar case that appears to confirm its a Salesforce limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Salesforce Flow Limitation - Relayed from another [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383149/flow-formulas-for-conditions-error-in-referenced-formula-because-of-lookup-a) - "*This is because Formulas in entry criteria that use Formula fields involving traversals are currently not supported by Salesforce. The workaround, for now, is to use the formula instead of the reference to that formula*"

Comment: good find!   And totally unexpected